# Assistance with PHP Soap request with attributes and nodes

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing, salesforce

Edit, see my last comment. I commented the code where I added the fullName to the metadata array.

I'm having an issue using the PHP Soap client to create the below XML Soap request. Problem I'm having is adding the fullName element as the child node to sObjects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn1="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<x:Header>
    <urn1:SessionHeader>
        <urn1:sessionId>a sessionid</urn1:sessionId>
    </urn1:SessionHeader>
    <urn1:MetadataWarningsHeader>
        <urn1:ignoreSaveWarnings>false</urn1:ignoreSaveWarnings>
    </urn1:MetadataWarningsHeader>
    <urn1:AllOrNoneHeader>
        <urn1:allOrNone>false</urn1:allOrNone>
    </urn1:AllOrNoneHeader>
    <urn1:CallOptions>
        <urn1:client/>
    </urn1:CallOptions>
</x:Header>
<x:Body>
    <urn1:create>
        <urn1:sObjects xsi:type="WorkflowFieldUpdate">
            <fullName>Lead.Tooling</fullName>
            <metadata>
                <field>Test_Field_Update__c</field>
                <name>Tooling</name>
                <notifyAssignee>false</notifyAssignee>
                <operation>Null</operation>
                <protected>false</protected>
            </metadata>
        </urn1:sObjects>
    </urn1:create>
</x:Body>
```

Here is the code I'm using in the create function. I get everything, but the fullName. I tried adding is as apart of an array with the Metadata node, but it's inserted as Bogus.

```
$field = new SoapVar('Test_Field_Update__c', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'field', null);
$name = new SoapVar('ToolingSample', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'name', null);
$notifyAssignee = new SoapVar(false, XSD_BOOLEAN, null, null, 'notifyAssignee');
$protected = new SoapVar(false, XSD_BOOLEAN, null, null, 'protected');
$operation = new SoapVar('Null', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'operation');
$fullname = new SoapVar('Lead.ToolingSample', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'fullName', null);

$metadata = new SoapVar(
    array($field, $name, $notifyAssignee, $protected, $operation),
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
    null,
    null,
    'Metadata'
);
// I needed change this line SoapVar
$metadataList = new SoapVar(array($metadata), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
// Fix: Is adding the fullName var to the $metadata array
$metadataList = SoapVar(array($metadata, $fullname), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

$sObject = new SoapVar($metadataList, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'WorkflowFieldUpdate', null, 'sObjects');
$sObjects = new SoapVar(array($sObject), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, null);

$response = $soapClient->create(new SoapVar($sObjects, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));

$ReturnArray = array('success' => true, 'data' => $response, 'types' => $metadataList, 'request' => $soapClient->__getLastRequest());

echo $_REQUEST['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($ReturnArray) . ')';
```

I tried changing the sObject Soapvar to this, but no go. I wasn't too confident it would work.

```
$sObject = new SoapVar(array($fullName, $metadataList), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'WorkflowFieldUpdate', null, 'sObjects')
```

Comment: I got it. I was putting $full name in the wrong place. I added it under this SoapVar. $metadataList = new SoapVar(array($metadata, $fullname), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

Answer (score 0):

Correct full code is below. See comments in code for fix. I will add a class later for the soap client and the different sObjects.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
error_reporting(-1);

$ReturnArray = null;

try {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['sessionId']) && isset($_REQUEST['serverUrl'])) {

        $sessionId = $_REQUEST['sessionId'];
        $serverUrl = str_replace('/u/', '/t/',$_REQUEST['serverUrl']);
        $namespace = 'urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com';

        $soapClientArray = array(
            'user_agent' => 'salesforce-toolkit-php/35.0',
            'encoding' => 'utf-8',
            'trace' => 1,
            'sessionId' => $sessionId
        );

        $sessionVar = array(
            'sessionId' => new SoapVar($sessionId, XSD_STRING)
        );

        $headerBody = new SoapVar(
            $sessionVar,
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT
        );

        $session_header = new SoapHeader(
            $namespace,
            'SessionHeader',
            $headerBody,
            false
        );

        $soapClient = new SoapClient('tooling.wsdl.xml', $soapClientArray);

        $header_array    = array(
            $session_header
        );

        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($header_array);

        $field = new SoapVar('Test_Field_Update__c', XSD_STRING, null, null,'field', null);
        $name = new SoapVar('ToolingSample', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'name', null);
        $notifyAssignee = new SoapVar(false, XSD_BOOLEAN, null, null, 'notifyAssignee');
        $protected = new SoapVar(false, XSD_BOOLEAN, null, null, 'protected');
        $operation = new SoapVar('Null', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'operation');
        $fullname = new SoapVar('Lead.ToolingSample', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'fullName', null);

        $metadata = new SoapVar(
            array(
                $field,
                $name, 
                $notifyAssignee,  
                $protected, $operation
            ),
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            null,
            null,
           'Metadata'
        );
        // I needed change this line SoapVar
        // $metadataList = new SoapVar(array($metadata), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
        // Fix: Is adding the fullName var to the $metadata array
        $metadataList = SoapVar(
            array($metadata, $fullname),
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT
        );

        $sObject = new SoapVar(
            $metadataList,
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            'WorkflowFieldUpdate',
            null,
            'sObjects'
        );

        $sObjects = new SoapVar(
            array($sObject),
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            null,
            null,
            null
        );

        $response = $soapClient->create(new SoapVar($sObjects, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
        // You can add anything to this array and it will post
        $ReturnArray = array(
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $response,
        );
    } else {
        $ReturnArray = array(
            'success'  => false,
            'data' => 'Unknown error'
        );
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $ReturnArray = array(
        'success'  => false,
        'data' => $e->getMessage()
    );
}
// This will output code in the console where it's easier to interpret
echo $_REQUEST['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($ReturnArray) . ')';
```